# I've wanted to copy and paste specific data on existing worksheet from workbook loaded

Tags: excel, vba

I've wanted to copy and paste specific data on existing worksheet from workbook loaded.

Code is running till get to below row..
(Please find full code on below)

```
rng.Copy worksheet("WMS").Cells(j, 39)
```

I guess it has problem with this
worksheet("WMS") (WMS worksheet is existing worksheet)in with loop but has no clue to solve this problem.

Would you give me advise what should I try?
thanks.

```vb
Private Sub btnMerge_Click()
 
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet: Dim toWS As Worksheet

Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long: i = 0: Dim j As Long
Dim endCol As Long: Dim endRow As Long
Dim strWS As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 
If Me.lstWB.ListCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No file have selected"
    Exit Sub
End If
 
Set toWS = ActiveSheet
j = toWS.Cells(toWS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 
For i = 0 To Me.lstWB.ListCount - 1
    Set WB = Application.Workbooks.Open(Me.lstWB.List(i))
    
    For Each WS In WB.Worksheets
    
            With WS
                endCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                endRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, endRow))
                
                rng.Copy worksheet("WMS").Cells(j, 39)
                j = j + rng.Rows.Count
 
            End With
    Next
    WB.Close
Next
 
MsgBox "Done"
Unload Me
 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 
End Sub
```

Comment: `rng.Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WMS").Cells(j, 39)` assuming the destination sheet is in the same workbook as the code.

Comment: ...also you're using `endRow` as a column index, and not using `endCol` at all

Comment: It's `Worksheets`, not `Worksheet`. Don't think, like, that you want "the worksheet named WMS". Actually, `Worksheets` is a `Collection` and from among all the worksheets you want the one called WMS. Hence the plural s.

Comment: @Variatus thanks! I just start to use VBA few days ago.. haven't got used to it but try to get used to it. I should do it from scratch..

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for you comment. I should have told that destination sheet is in different work book.  [rng.Copy Workbooks("File_merge.xlsm").Worksheets("WMS").Cells(j, 39)] I thought it would work but return error again..

Comment: "return error" isn't a very useful description of what happens when you run your code.  What is the specific error you get?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, endRow))
```

to

```
Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(endRow, endCol))
```

Using variant array is more effective.
`.rows.count`  is same  with `rows.count`. Because the number of rows of all sheets is the same.

```
Private Sub btnMerge_Click()
 
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet: Dim toWS As Worksheet

Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long: i = 0: Dim j As Long
Dim endCol As Long: Dim endRow As Long
Dim strWS As String
Dim Target As Range, vDB As Variant


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 
If Me.lstWB.ListCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No file have selected"
    Exit Sub
End If
 
Set toWS = ActiveSheet
'j = toWS.Cells(toWS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 
For i = 0 To Me.lstWB.ListCount - 1
    Set WB = Application.Workbooks.Open(Me.lstWB.List(i))
    
    For Each WS In WB.Worksheets
    
            With WS
                endCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                endRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                'Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, endRow))
                vDB = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(endRow, endCol))

                'rng.Copy Worksheet("WMS").Cells(j, 39)
                Set Target = toWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 39).End(xlUp)(2)
                'j = j + rng.Rows.Count
                Target.Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB
 
            End With
    Next
    WB.Close
Next
 
MsgBox "Done"
Unload Me
 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 
End Sub
```